# PhoneGap (Cordova) app crashes when loading google chart API

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, google-visualization

**I'm testing this app on a iOS Simulator**

Whenever I run this code:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
```

My phonegap application crashes to a completely white screen. I have a page, where I have some random content and a button, that is assigned a `.click()` `jQuery` listener to start loading the google chart api. Whenever I click that button, everything dissapears and I'm left with a blank screen.

Here's the code:

```
$( '#chartsThirdStep' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){

    $("#chartThirdStepGoButton").click(function(event){

        parseChartInfo();
    });
});

function parseChartInfo() {

    console.log("parseChartInfo()");
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    // app completely crashes here - all jquery mobile stuff dissapears
    // and i'm left with a blank screen on the simulator.
    //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
}
```

I'm using:

- Xcode v4.2
- Cordova v1.9.0
- jQuery mobile v1.1.1
- jQuery v1.7.1
- https://www.google.com/jsapi
- Mac OS X v10.6.8
- iOS Simulator v5.0 (272)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first, you need to load the API outside the "ready" event handler, as the loader doesn't seem to work properly inside other functions.
Second, put the click event handler inside the google.load callback, which will prevent the click event from being assigned before the API loads (and thus users can't try to draw charts before the API loads, though it typically loads sufficiently fast that your users should never notice a difference)

Comment: I was hitting the white screen problem as well, and I had to cheat a bit.  For my PhoneGap+JQM app, I actually did the google.load in my initialization and had setOnLoadCallback set a flag stating it was ready.  I then had a setInterval() monitor the flag for it being set.

Comment: I was able to move on from this solution. Forgot to give credit, doing so now - thanks!

Comment: +1. Had to move the `google.load()` snippet to the head. Crashed my webapp in desktop browsers.